# Dynamically Loaded Data on AmMaps even.MapObject.id undefined

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I have an ammaps map (USALOW) and I am loading it dynamically. How can I get the id to come back for the state I clicked? WHen I add the below code it keeps alerting my undefined:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
            alert(event.mapObject.id);
        });
```

Here is my map script:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: mapData,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            //getLabelColor(item.StateCode, assignMapColor(item.Obligation));
            newmapdata.push({
                id: "US-" + item.GeoCode,
                title: item.GeoName,
                value: item.GrantTotal,
                balloonText: "<b>" + item.GeoName +
                    "</b>" + "<br>Grant Amount: $" + item.GrantTotal.toLocaleString(),
                color: "#0a71b2"
            });
        });

        var map = AmCharts.makeChart("grantsMap", {
            type: "map",
            "theme": "light",
            dragMap: true,
            fixedSize: false,

            colorSteps: 10,
            "responsive": {
                "enabled": true,
                // Rules
                "rules": [
                // at 500px wide, we hide baloons
                {
                    "maxWidth": 500,
                    "overrides": {
                        "balloon": {
                            "enabled": false
                        },
                        "imagesSettings": {
                            "labelPosition": "middle",
                            "labelFontSize": 8
                        }

                    }
                }
                ]
            },
            // End of Rules
            "areasSettings": {
                "autozoom": true,
                outlineColor: "#000000",
                "selectable": true
            },
            dataProvider: {
                map: "usaLow",
                areas: newmapdata,
                getAreasFromMap: true,
                images: [
                {
                    label: "AL",
                    latitude: -40,
                    longitude: 81,
                    linkToObject: "US-AL"
                }, {
                    label: "AK",
                    latitude: -84,
                    longitude: -130,
                    linkToObject: "US-AK"
                }, {
                    label: "AZ",
                    latitude: -4,
                    longitude: -85,
                    linkToObject: "US-AZ"
                }, {
                    label: "AR",
                    latitude: -11,
                    longitude: 41,
                    linkToObject: "US-AR"
                }, {
                    label: "CA",
                    latitude: 70,
                    longitude: -135,
                    linkToObject: "US-CA"
                }, {
                    label: "CO",
                    latitude: 60,
                    longitude: -42,
                    linkToObject: "US-CO"
                }, {
                    "label": "CT",
                    "latitude": 71,
                    "longitude": 180,
                    "linkToObject": "US-CT",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "DE",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    latitude: 38,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-DE",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    label: "DC",
                    latitude: -20,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-DC",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "FL",
                    latitude: -78,
                    longitude: 120,
                    linkToObject: "US-FL"
                }, {
                    label: "GA",
                    latitude: -40,
                    longitude: 102,
                    linkToObject: "US-GA"
                }, {
                    label: "HI",
                    latitude: -88.7,
                    longitude: -35.7,
                    linkToObject: "US-HI"
                }, {
                    label: "ID",
                    latitude: 85,
                    longitude: -85,
                    linkToObject: "US-ID"
                }, {
                    label: "IL",
                    latitude: 65,
                    longitude: 60,
                    linkToObject: "US-IL"
                }, {
                    label: "IN",
                    latitude: 67,
                    longitude: 78,
                    linkToObject: "US-IN"
                }, {
                    label: "IA",
                    latitude: 77,
                    longitude: 35,
                    linkToObject: "US-IA"
                }, {
                    label: "KS",
                    latitude: 48,
                    longitude: 5,
                    linkToObject: "US-KS"
                }, {
                    label: "KY",
                    latitude: 42,
                    longitude: 87,
                    linkToObject: "US-KY"
                }, {
                    label: "LA",
                    latitude: -65,
                    longitude: 43,
                    linkToObject: "US-LA"
                }, {
                    label: "ME",
                    latitude: 88.3,
                    longitude: 168,
                    linkToObject: "US-ME"
                }, {
                    label: "MD",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    latitude: 10,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-MD",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "MA",
                    latitude: 83.5,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-MA",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8,
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",

                }, {
                    label: "MI",
                    latitude: 82.7,
                    longitude: 85,
                    linkToObject: "US-MI"
                }, {
                    label: "MO",
                    latitude: 48,
                    longitude: 40,
                    linkToObject: "US-MO"
                }, {
                    label: "MN",
                    latitude: 87,
                    longitude: 28,
                    linkToObject: "US-MN"
                }, {
                    label: "MS",
                    latitude: -40,
                    longitude: 61,
                    linkToObject: "US-MS"
                }, {
                    label: "MT",
                    latitude: 88.2,
                    longitude: -55,
                    linkToObject: "US-MT"
                }, {
                    label: "NE",
                    latitude: 75,
                    longitude: 0,
                    linkToObject: "US-NE"
                }, {
                    label: "NV",
                    latitude: 75,
                    longitude: -107,
                    linkToObject: "US-NV"
                }, {
                    label: "NH",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    latitude: 86.2,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-NH",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "NJ",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    latitude: 58,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-NJ",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "NM",
                    latitude: -10,
                    longitude: -46,
                    linkToObject: "US-NM"
                }, {
                    label: "NY",
                    latitude: 85,
                    longitude: 140,
                    linkToObject: "US-NY"
                }, {
                    label: "NC",
                    latitude: 23,
                    longitude: 128,
                    linkToObject: "US-NC"
                }, {
                    label: "ND",
                    latitude: 88,
                    longitude: -5,
                    linkToObject: "US-ND"
                }, {
                    label: "OH",
                    latitude: 70,
                    longitude: 98,
                    linkToObject: "US-OH"
                }, {
                    label: "OK",
                    latitude: -6,
                    longitude: 11,
                    linkToObject: "US-OK"
                }, {
                    label: "OR",
                    latitude: 87,
                    longitude: -122,
                    linkToObject: "US-OR"
                }, {
                    label: "PA",
                    latitude: 78,
                    longitude: 128,
                    linkToObject: "US-PA"
                }, {
                    label: "RI",
                    //labelBackgroundColor: "#cccccc",
                    latitude: 79,
                    longitude: 180,
                    linkToObject: "US-RI",
                    labelBackgroundAlpha: .8
                }, {
                    label: "SC",
                    latitude: -12,
                    longitude: 117,
                    linkToObject: "US-SC"
                }, {
                    label: "SD",
                    latitude: 84.5,
                    longitude: -5,
                    linkToObject: "US-SD"
                }, {
                    label: "TN",
                    latitude: 12,
                    longitude: 83,
                    linkToObject: "US-TN"
                }, {
                    label: "TX",
                    latitude: -65,
                    longitude: 0,
                    linkToObject: "US-TX"
                }, {
                    label: "UT",
                    latitude: 66,
                    longitude: -77,
                    linkToObject: "US-UT"
                }, {
                    label: "VT",
                    latitude: 87,
                    longitude: 150.5,
                    linkToObject: "US-VT"
                }, {
                    label: "VA",
                    latitude: 55,
                    longitude: 128,
                    linkToObject: "US-VA"
                }, {
                    label: "WA",
                    latitude: 89,
                    longitude: -112,
                    linkToObject: "US-WA"
                }, {
                    label: "WV",
                    latitude: 60,
                    longitude: 112,
                    linkToObject: "US-WV"
                }, {
                    label: "WI",
                    latitude: 85,
                    longitude: 53,
                    linkToObject: "US-WI"
                }, {
                    label: "WY",
                    latitude: 82.5,
                    longitude: -47,
                    linkToObject: "US-WY"
                }
                ],
                lines: [
                    {
                        //DC LINE
                        latitudes: [66.8921, -20],
                        longitudes: [135.6241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //CT LINE
                        latitudes: [82.8921, 71],
                        longitudes: [153.8241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //DE LINE
                        latitudes: [69.0921, 38],
                        longitudes: [145.2241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //MD LINE
                        latitudes: [69.8921, 10],
                        longitudes: [136.8241, 172.5]
                    }, {
                        //MA LINE
                        latitudes: [84.0921, 83],
                        longitudes: [153.8241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //NH LINE
                        latitudes: [86.0921, 86.2],
                        longitudes: [156.8241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //NJ LINE
                        latitudes: [76.0921, 58],
                        longitudes: [147.8241, 173]
                    }, {
                        //RI LINE
                        latitudes: [83.0921, 78],
                        longitudes: [162.8241, 173.5]
                    }
                ]
            },

            zoomControl: {
                zoomControlEnabled: true,
                panControlEnabled: false
            },

            "imagesSettings": {
                "labelPosition": "middle",
                "labelFontSize": 11
            }

        });

        map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
            alert(event.mapObject.id);
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = '<p> <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/drugresistance/solutions-initiative/infographics/drug-resistant-lab-network-infographic.jpg" /> </p>';
            document.getElementById("pdfDownload").innerHTML = event.mapObject.id + '<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>'
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your states are working correctly, but your images (labels) are returning undefined as the IDs are undefined by default unless set. Giving your images IDs fixes the problem:

```
    images: [{
      id: "AL",
      label: "AL",
      latitude: -40,
      longitude: 81,
      linkToObject: "US-AL"
    }, {
      id: "AK",
      label: "AK",
      latitude: -84,
      longitude: -130,
      linkToObject: "US-AK"
    }, 
      // ...
    ]
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lke5apLv/1).